# Why is Microsoft IIS so fast compared to nginx?

Tags: windows, nginx, iis

According to [this](http://www.gtcomm.net/blog/nginx-the-best-http-server/) post with benchmarks, IIS consistently outperforms nginx in speed. Specifically, IIS uses 2.3x less CPU power than nginx, processes more than double the requests, and responds in less than half the time.

The blog post says nothing more about what IIS does internally to make it so fast. It simply states:

> IIS, when used in conjunction with a Windows OS is fast and reliable.

I would like to know what exactly IIS (or perhaps Windows NT) does to make it so much faster than nginx on Linux. I was unable to find any other information on exactly what makes IIS so fast. I did, however, find [another benchmark](http://www.webperformance.com/load-testing/blog/2011/11/what-is-the-fastest-webserver/) that agrees with the first one.

Comment: There isn't enough information provided about those benchmarks to determine if they are actually comparable, i.e. that they performed the tests correctly.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I have added another source

Comment: @john01dav The additional source is benchmarking nginx on a *Windows* server, which IMO is a very, very iffy pick.

Comment: It doesn't say it's faster. It only says it's fast. And only when working with Windows. But the article also states that nginx is fast. So it is not saying IIS has any advantage over nginx.

Comment: Seems @john01dav is correct. Here is another link that proves his claim: https://www.rootusers.com/linux-vs-windows-web-server-benchmarks/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm extremely skeptical about these results. While IIS may be faster, both posts do not mention anything specific about the hardware, OS settings(filesystem mount options, io schedulers, network buffers, tcp stakck setting and so on), web server config.
Modern http servers are extremely complex animals, you can turn on and off huge amount of options, modules.
In order to do a relevant test you need to be testing all servers in similar conditions and with similar functionality enabled. Without this its apples and oranges.

Comment: Also the statement "IIS, when used in conjunction with a Windows OS is fast and reliable." Is kinda hilarious, what other OS you can use it with?

Comment: Maybe IIS runs on Xenix ;)

Comment: It doesn't say it's faster. It only says it's fast. And only when working with Windows. But the article also states that nginx is fast. So it is not saying IIS has any advantage over nginx.

Answer (score 1):

This is very doubtful. We had deployed a web api (.net core 3.1) with iis, and in NGINX with Ubuntu. The response time with nginx was 1/3 of iis. Didn't performed a load test. But another big thing is that we had 8gb machine for both ubuntu and windows server and in windows server 2.5 gb of ram  was eaten by OS itself. Where as ram consumption of ubuntu was lesser and altogether it was less than 1 Gb including the application.

Answer (score 0):

- keyword 1 - IOCP - better than epoll Nginx used in theory
- keyword 2 - http.sys - some parts of IIS are run in kernel space

Comment: The article makes no claim for having any advantage over nginx. It only states IIS is fast but it says the same thing about nginx.

Answer (score 0):

The performance difference is probably negligible. The main strength of IIS is ease of use and that means cost savings as you don't spend days, weeks even on a very basic task like organise different web apps under a single site and folder hiarchy that is so easy to do with IIS, takes 30 seconds and doesn't depend of URL rewriting and other unpleasant things, weird behaviour as nginx configuration rules have a steeper learning curve, u don't just run publish in visual studio and that's that.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://serverfault.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://serverfault.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/529098)

Answer (score 0):

These are some the parameters that can affect performance of a web/application server: -

System capacity: RAM, Type of RAM, System L1 Cache, System L2 Cache, Processor capacity, System Bus capacity, Type of disk, Operating System, File System architecture.

Web/Application Server: Type/Version of Web/Application server, Web request handling capacity, Capacity of indexing capability, Capacity of scaling up/down on need base, Object instances handling capability, Memory management capability.

Network: Network capacity, Network connectivity and Network I/O handling capacity.

Version of Web/Application server: The performance can vary across different versions of the same Web/Application server.

For performance comparison, there should be only one variable.

We need to have clarity on what is the performance test specification.